# Google Cloud Managed Instance Group cannot be deleted and Autoscaler cannot be modified

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The title basically encapsulates the problem.

After attempting to automate scaling a region-based managed instance group on google cloud platform, the MIG seems to have gotten itself into an inconsistent state that hasn't cleared after 3 days.
When I attempt modify the autoscaler, using either the stable or beta CLI:

```
~ $ gcloud beta compute instance-groups managed update-autoscaling instance-group-1 --mode OFF --project project-1 --region europe-west2
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.instance-groups.managed.update-autoscaling) Could not fetch resource:
 - Resource 'projects/project-1/regions/europe-west2/autoscalers/instance-group-1' has an ongoing conflicting operation: ''.

~ $ gcloud compute instance-groups managed update-autoscaling instance-group-1 --mode OFF --project project-1 --region europe-west2
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instance-groups.managed.update-autoscaling) Could not fetch resource:
 - Resource 'projects/project-1/regions/europe-west2/autoscalers/instance-group-1' has an ongoing conflicting operation: ''.
```

When I attempts a straight delete of the MIG, the command line simply hangs.

There doesn't seem to be any mechanism to force these operations or clear conflicts.  Are there any other options short of opening a support ticket with google to resolve this?

Comment: Are there any errors shown with [`gcloud compute instance-groups managed list-errors ...`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/list-errors)   ?

Comment: The only errors there have to do with shortage of resource in one of the two zones that my region MIG is configured for. This has been increasingly common when trying to allocate GPU in London, but I don't think this is related.

Comment: Please also try to contact the Google Cloud Support.